# Rename strings systematically in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, grepl

I have a string vector like this:

```
s <- c("X _1", 
       "X _2",
       "X _3",
       "X _4",
       "X _5",
       "X _6",
       "X _7",
       "X _8")
```

Is there a way of systematically renaming the variables such that, for example, `X _1` becomes `X_1`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` (or `gsub` if more than one instance of space) to match the space and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub(" ", "", s)
[1] "X_1" "X_2" "X_3" "X_4" "X_5" "X_6" "X_7" "X_8"
```